# Auto update row in mysql with the same id

Tags: mysql

I used to use `UNIQUE KEY id (id)` in my table, but whenever a new row with the same id inserted, the new one will be ignored and keep the old row in table.

what I wanna do is to keep the id unique by updating the old row with the new one whenever a new row inserted. Any sugestions?

Comment: I guess you are looking for something like `on duplicate key update` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert into a MySQL table or update if exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists)

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql triggers and do this easily.

> A trigger is a set of actions that are run automatically when a
>   specified change operation (SQL INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement)
>   is performed on a specified table. Triggers are useful for tasks such
>   as enforcing business rules, validating input data, and keeping an
>   audit trail.

This [link](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-triggers.php) explains on how to achieve this and what are the pros etc..